# Glitch in pages transition

Tags: html, css, transition

I hope you are fine.

I am currently creating my portfolio on Cargo, it is almost finished but I have a small problem.

There is regularly a glitch that appears when changing pages, it appears some frames and it's quite random. Is there a way to limit this?

Here is a video where you can see the glitch:
https://vimeo.com/558958463/f3da790909

Thank you in advance,
Léo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the height of the header is getting applied on page load. If there is some custom CSS that is not in the `<head>` of the page, the webpage will start displaying before the CSS rules are applied. This can cause the header to first be one height before changing to the new height.